# Retrieve parameter from hidden url

Tags: javascript

I'm making a webpage which has articles.
I decided to make my url look pretty by using text rather than variables.
Ex:

> Input: page.com/article/test-article
>
> Output: page.com/article.php?id=1
>
> Visible: page.com/article/test-article

I'm trying to get my the id parameter in js!
The function people seem to recommend is this one:

```
function getUrlVars() {
    alert("url: " + window.location.href);
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,
        function(m, key, value) {
            vars[key] = value;
        }
    );
    return vars;
}
```

Problem is, I need the OUTPUT url from my example here... not the input.
What can I do to grab that?

Comment: Note: The url is handled using htaccess

Answer (score 0):

If you are rewriting the url in `.htaccess`, then it is being done on the server, and there is no way for client side JavaScript to know what the "real" URL is without some help. Fortunately, it looks like you are using PHP, so you can mix some server side code in with your JavaScript with something like:

```
 var realUrl = "<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ?>"
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work. I just get the same php code output with a alert(realUrl) not the actual url.

Comment: @AleksanderFimreite that's odd. Is your other PHP code on the page working?

Comment: Yep, I added my youtube video (content) to my article from there. Except I wanted more than just the youtube video there, so I needed to get the title from js. thus I needed another way of getting the id.

Comment: But nvm. I found a work around that works. I just need this formula for youtube videos. I feed my most recent videos to my homepage, from there its id will be passed through the url to a file invisibly. ex: .../youtube/MYVIDEOID

And I think that is fair enough since all the other articles has an actuall name.